# After inserting data into one table, I also want that data to auto appear in another table

Tags: c#, sql, database, select

I have two buttons, one when clicked will go to medication form, another when clicked will go to prescription form. What I want to achieve is, if I entered one record in the medication form, the prescription form will auto generate a prescriptionID and pop up the medicationName based on what medication name that I typed on the medication form.

For the field medicationName in prescription form, it was orginally a medicationID, but I used left outer join to display as medicationName which exist in medication table.

For the attached first image, the reason the prescription form have a panadol record is because I type a number 3 medicationID in the prescription database. I don;t want to manually type it in the database, I want it to auto pop up whenever i insert a record in medication form. See, when I insert record with a strong panadol, it didn;t appear in the prescription form!!!!!

PRESCRIPTION AND MEDICATION FORM
[image: output]

PRESCRIPTION TABLE
[image: prescriptiontable]

MEDICATION TABLE
[image: medicationtable]

Error after keying value and clicking submit button in medication form.
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'panadol3' to data type int.
[image: Error]

//PRESCRIPTION FORM CODES

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class prescription : Form
    {

        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Prescription = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter PrescriptionAdapter;

        public prescription()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void prescription_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPrescriptionRecords();
        }

        private void LoadPrescriptionRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, med.medicationName FROM PRESCRIPTION AS pres";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN medication as med on pres.medicationid = med.medicationid";

            PrescriptionAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PrescriptionAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Prescription.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            PrescriptionAdapter.Fill(Prescription);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Prescription.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdPrescription.DataSource = Prescription;
        }

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this displays the dialog box and performs actions dependant on which option chosen.
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int columnPosition = 0;
            int rowPosition = 25;

            // run function to draw headers
            DrawHeader(new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition); // runs the DrawHeader function

            rowPosition += 35; // sets the distance below the header text and the next black line (ruler)

            // run function to draw each row
            DrawGridBody(e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition);
        }

        // DrawHeader will draw the column title, move over, draw the next column title, move over, and continue.
        private int DrawHeader(Font boldFont, Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdPrescription.Columns)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show("dc = " + dc);

                g.DrawString(dc.HeaderText, boldFont, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition);
                columnPosition += dc.Width + 5; // adds to colPos. value the width value of the column + 5. 
            }

            return columnPosition;
        }

        /* DrawGridBody will loop though each row and draw it on the screen. It starts by drawing a solid line on the screen, 
         * then it moves down a row and draws the data from the first grid column, then it moves over, then draws the data from the next column,
         * moves over, draws the data from the next column, and continus this pattern. When the entire row is drawn it starts over and draws
         * a solid line then the row data, then the next solid line and then row data, etc.
        */
        private void DrawGridBody(Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            // loop through each row and draw the data to the graphics surface.
            foreach (DataRow dr in ((DataTable)grdPrescription.DataSource).Rows)
            {
                columnPosition = 0;

                // draw a line to separate the rows 
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, rowPosition), new Point(this.Width, rowPosition));

                // loop through each column in the row, and draw the individual data item
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdPrescription.Columns)
                {
                    // draw string in the column
                    string text = dr[dc.DataPropertyName].ToString();
                    g.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition + 10f); // the last number (10f) sets the space between the black line (ruler) and the text below it.

                    // go to the next column position
                    columnPosition += dc.Width + 5;
                }

                // go to the next row position
                rowPosition = rowPosition + 60; // this sets the space between the row text and the black line below it (ruler).
            }
        }

        private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog(); // instantiate new print preview dialog
                printPreviewDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;
                if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Show the print preview dialog, uses printPage event to draw preview screen
                {
                    printDocument1.Print();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(exp.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MEDICATION FORM codes. This is my code in the insertprescription trigger.

ALTER TRIGGER insertPrescriptions ON dbo.MEDICATION AFTER INSERT AS INSERT INTO prescription(prescriptionID, medicationID) select MedicationID, MedicationName from inserted GO

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class medication : Form
    {
        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Medication = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter MedicationAdapter;

        public medication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnSubmit.Text == "Clear")
            {
                btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
                ClearTextBoxes();
                txtmedicationType.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                btnSubmit.Text = "Clear";
                int result = AddMedicationRecord();
                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Successful");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Fail");

            }
        }
        private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            txtmedicationType.Clear();
            txtmedicationName.Clear();
            txtexpiryDate.Clear();
            txtmedicationPrice.Clear();
        }

        private int AddMedicationRecord()
        {
            int result = 0;
            // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                //STEP 2: Create command
 String strCommandText = "INSERT MEDICATION(medicationType, medicationName, expiryDate, medicationPrice) "
                + " VALUES (@NewmedicationType, @NewmedicationName,@NewexpiryDate, @NewmedicationPrice)";

            SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);


            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmedicationName", txtmedicationName.Text);
            //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
            myConnect.Open();
            // STEP 4: execute command
            // indicates number of record updated.
            result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // STEP 5: Close
            myConnect.Close();
            return result;

        }

        private void medication_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadMedicationRecords();
        }

        private void LoadMedicationRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT medicationID, medicationType, medicationName, expiryDate, medicationPrice FROM MEDICATION";

            MedicationAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(MedicationAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Medication.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            MedicationAdapter.Fill(Medication);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Medication.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdMedication.DataSource = Medication;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int modifiedRows = 0;
            // Get changes
            DataTable UpdatedTable = Medication.GetChanges();
            if (UpdatedTable != null)
            {
                // there are changes
                // Write modified data to database 
                modifiedRows = MedicationAdapter.Update(UpdatedTable);
                // accept changes
                Medication.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("there are no changes to update");

            if (modifiedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + modifiedRows + " records updated");
                LoadMedicationRecords();
            }
        }

        private void grdMedication_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            MedicationAdapter.Update(Medication);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What about using the event valuechanged of medicationform to refresh the prescriptionform!

Comment: How to create that event valuechanged? and wat codes to put in? @FeliceM

Comment: I do not know what you are using there. However  assuming you are using a dagridview, look for DataGridView.CellValueChanged and then write the code in such event to refresh/update the second grid. Something like MedicationAdapter.Update(Medication)

Comment: so by doing this, it will insert a record into prescription table database each time i insert a record in medication table using the medication form?  @FeliceM

Comment: ya i use a datagridview. I think u got the wrong idea. I mean it doesn't even insert to my prescription table database in the first place. I want whenever I insert a record in medication using the form, a record will also be entered in the prescription table database also, with just a auto increment prescriptionID and the medicationName that i insert using the medication form. @FeliceM

Comment: I do not have the wrong idea. The problem is that your code does not even work with the basic features you are trying to implement  and you ask a question on how to uptaed/refresh a second table when a value is inserted in the first table. Sort out your basic problems first and then implement the method as above described.

Comment: Oh sorry, ok i edit and post my whole codes of the page already. I generate the event valuechanged alr, and put in that medicationadapter code. What should I do next? still has no effect. @FeliceM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you want the row in the second table 100% of the time, a real simple way would be an after insert trigger. You could also add triggers for updates and deletes if you need them.  If you need to insert it conditionally then you probably to sort it out in code.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=SQL.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: omg too complicated for me. I am doing this for my sch project. @drewlander

Comment: oh, its not that bad.  It might not work for you if its an assignment because teachers might be looking for a specific solution, but the gist of it is, if you add this trigger on the medications table it should insert a record into the prescriptions table every time.  You could make similar triggers for update and deletes.  `CREATE TRIGGER insertPrescriptions
ON Medications
 AFTER INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO prescriptions(MedicationID, MedicationName)
select MedicationID, MedicationName from inserted
GO`

Comment: Thanks, oh its ok, I think I just need it to work, then it's good already. I tried to follow your code, I posted my updated codes above on medication form. I got error, when i type in a medication name and press the submit button. what's wrong?                                 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.               @drewlander

Comment: you create the trigger in the database, not in your code.  ;-) I wrote that directly to stackoverflow. Ill try to open up ssms to create your tables and verify the syntax just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks man. But I found out where to type in the trigger codes, right click on medication table and click add new trigger right? I got error tho. I added a new image above, and I show my trigger statements above, i edited the trigger codes that you gave me. I think it's because the prescription table, the medicationID is in int, and the medicationName in medication table is in nvachar. because I need use left outer join to display the medicationname from medication table. From medicationID changed to medicationName in prescription form. So how man. @drewlander

Comment: Yeah man... if your prescriptions table has an auto increment on prescriptionID, and you need to insert the medicationID, then you would do this: `ALTER TRIGGER insertPrescriptions ON dbo.MEDICATION AFTER INSERT AS INSERT INTO prescription(medicationID) select MedicationID from inserted GO` because the prescriptionid will fill itself in.  Then when you select on the prescription table you should probably not left outer, but instead inner join on the medication table with the medication ID, unless for some reason you expect a record will not be in both tables.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply. It worked tho. Both inner join or left outer join worked. Thanks. @drewlander

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is event based, so try to things about your problems as "When XXX happens, I want to do YYY".

In your case, if I understand correctly, you want:

- When a Medication row is added (not edited, only added)

  - Create a Prescription row linked to that Medication
  - Update/refresh the Prescription form to show the new row

There are events that you can hook into, and you can do you own events if you like.

Does that give you enough to work it out, or would you like more help?